# Html: The page footer and a long form get overlapped

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I am using a [ready-made template](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/paper-kit) as my css/html skills are very humble and I am more comfortable with backend development.

This is the pre-defined login page:
[image]

In the register-page (which contains many more fields) that I created based on the pre-defined login page:
[image]
**Notice how the footer get mixed-up with the form.**
This is the html code:

```
 <>
      <ExamplesNavbar />
      <div
        className="page-header"
        style={{
          backgroundImage: "url(" + require("assets/img/login-image.jpg") + ")",
        }}
      >
        <div className="filter" />
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Col className="ml-auto mr-auto" lg="4">
              <Card className="card-register ml-auto mr-auto">
                <h3 className="title mx-auto">Welcome</h3>
                <div className="social-line text-center">
                  <Button
                    className="btn-neutral btn-just-icon mr-1"
                    color="facebook"
                    href="#pablo"
                    onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                  >
                    <i className="fa fa-facebook-square" />
                  </Button>
                  <Button
                    className="btn-neutral btn-just-icon mr-1"
                    color="google"
                    href="#pablo"
                    onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                  >
                    <i className="fa fa-google-plus" />
                  </Button>
                  <Button
                    className="btn-neutral btn-just-icon"
                    color="twitter"
                    href="#pablo"
                    onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                  >
                    <i className="fa fa-twitter" />
                  </Button>
                </div>
                <Form className="register-form">
                  <label>First name</label>
                  <Input placeholder="First name" type="text" />
                  <label>Surname</label>
                  <Input placeholder="Surname" type="text" />
                  <label>Email</label>
                  <Input placeholder="Email" type="text" />
                  <label>Password</label>
                  <Input placeholder="Password" type="password" />
                  <label>Confirm password</label>
                  <Input placeholder="Password" type="password" />
                  <label>Birthday</label>
                  <Input placeholder="date placeholder" type="date" />
                  <label>Country</label>
                  <CountryDropdown
                    style={{ width: "100%" }}
                    value={"Tunisia"}
                    // onChange={(val) => this.selectCountry(val)}
                  />
                  <Button block className="btn-round" color="danger">
                    Login
                  </Button>
                </Form>
                <div className="forgot">
                  <Button
                    className="btn-link"
                    color="danger"
                    href="#pablo"
                    onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                  >
                    Forgot password?
                  </Button>
                </div>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
        <div className="footer register-footer text-center">
          <h6>
            © {new Date().getFullYear()}, made with{" "}
            <i className="fa fa-heart heart" /> by Creative Tim
          </h6>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
```

I'm a bit suprised this happens since I've never seen html elements overlapping. But as I said my front-end skills and knoweldge is still being built-up. So if anyone could offer an explanation/solution for this, I'd be more than grateful.

---

**NOTE:** This is built using Reactstrap.

Comment: I tried to use your form field in the live template. This is what i see https://snipboard.io/UDHBLu.jpg have you changed any css values?

Comment: @KarthickManoharan no, I just increased the number of the form fields. I think this has something to do with how the template itself was built.

Comment: Did you check the image link that i shared. It had got all the fields from you form yet i do see the issue over footer overlapping other elements. Could you also share the css?

Comment: @KarthickManoharan check out my answser. I've solved it

Answer (score 0):

For some reason when I changed the react code from a function component to a stateful component, the problem disapeared:
[image]

```
function RegisterPage() {
  document.documentElement.classList.remove("nav-open");
  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.body.classList.add("register-page");
    return function cleanup() {
      document.body.classList.remove("register-page");
    };
  });
  return (
    <>
      <ExamplesNavbar />
      <div
        className="page-header"
        style={{
          backgroundImage: "url(" + require("assets/img/login-image.jpg") + ")",
        }}
      >
        <div className="filter" />
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Col className="ml-auto mr-auto" lg="4">
              <Card className="card-register ml-auto mr-auto">
                <h3 className="title mx-auto">Welcome</h3>
                <div className="social-line text-center">
                  <Button
                    className="btn-neutral btn-just-icon mr-1"
                    color="facebook"
                    href="#pablo"
                    onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                  >
                    <i className="fa fa-facebook-square" />
                  </Button>
                  <Button
                    className="btn-neutral btn-just-icon mr-1"
                    color="google"
                    href="#pablo"
                    onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                  >
                    <i className="fa fa-google-plus" />
                  </Button>
                  <Button
                    className="btn-neutral btn-just-icon"
                    color="twitter"
                    href="#pablo"
                    onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                  >
                    <i className="fa fa-twitter" />
                  </Button>
                </div>
                <Form className="register-form">
                  <label>First name</label>
                  <Input
                    placeholder="First name"
                    type="text"
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      console.log(e.target.value);
                    }}
                  />
                  <label>Surname</label>
                  <Input placeholder="Surname" type="text" />
                  <label>Email</label>
                  <Input placeholder="Email" type="text" />
                  <label>Password</label>
                  <Input placeholder="Password" type="password" />
                  <label>Confirm password</label>
                  <Input placeholder="Password" type="password" />
                  <label>Birthday</label>
                  <Input placeholder="date placeholder" type="date" />
                  <label>Country</label>
                  <CountryDropdown
                    style={{ width: "100%" }}
                    value={"Tunisia"}
                    // onChange={(val) => this.selectCountry(val)}
                  />
                  <Button block className="btn-round" color="danger">
                    Login
                  </Button>
                </Form>
                <div className="forgot">
                  <Button
                    className="btn-link"
                    color="danger"
                    href="#pablo"
                    onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                  >
                    Forgot password?
                  </Button>
                </div>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
        <div className="footer register-footer text-center">
          <h6>
            © {new Date().getFullYear()}, made with{" "}
            <i className="fa fa-heart heart" /> by Creative Tim
          </h6>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

To this:

```
export class RegisterPage extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      email: "",
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <ExamplesNavbar />
        <div
          className="page-header"
          style={{
            backgroundImage:
              "url(" + require("assets/img/login-image.jpg") + ")",
          }}
        >
          <div className="filter" />
          <Container>
            <Row>
              <Col className="ml-auto mr-auto" lg="4">
                <Card className="card-register ml-auto mr-auto">
                  <h3 className="title mx-auto">Welcome</h3>
                  <div className="social-line text-center">
                    <Button
                      className="btn-neutral btn-just-icon mr-1"
                      color="facebook"
                      href="#pablo"
                      onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                    >
                      <i className="fa fa-facebook-square" />
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                      className="btn-neutral btn-just-icon mr-1"
                      color="google"
                      href="#pablo"
                      onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                    >
                      <i className="fa fa-google-plus" />
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                      className="btn-neutral btn-just-icon"
                      color="twitter"
                      href="#pablo"
                      onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                    >
                      <i className="fa fa-twitter" />
                    </Button>
                  </div>
                  <Form className="register-form">
                    <label>First name</label>
                    <Input
                      placeholder="First name"
                      type="text"
                      onChange={(e) => {
                        console.log(e.target.value);
                      }}
                    />
                    <label>Surname</label>
                    <Input placeholder="Surname" type="text" />
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <Input placeholder="Email" type="text" />
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <Input placeholder="Password" type="password" />
                    <label>Confirm password</label>
                    <Input placeholder="Password" type="password" />
                    <label>Birthday</label>
                    <Input placeholder="date placeholder" type="date" />
                    <label>Country</label>
                    <CountryDropdown
                      style={{ width: "100%" }}
                      value={"Tunisia"}
                      // onChange={(val) => this.selectCountry(val)}
                    />
                    <Button block className="btn-round" color="danger">
                      Login
                    </Button>
                  </Form>
                  <div className="forgot">
                    <Button
                      className="btn-link"
                      color="danger"
                      href="#pablo"
                      onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                    >
                      Forgot password?
                    </Button>
                  </div>
                </Card>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
          <div className="footer register-footer text-center">
            <h6>
              © {new Date().getFullYear()}, made with{" "}
              <i className="fa fa-heart heart" /> by Creative Tim
            </h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```